# Concatenating JavaScript files with Prepros fails

Tags: javascript, prepros

I have this little `cat.js` file:

```
var Cat = (function( cat ){

    cat.speak = function(){ return 'meew'; };

    return cat;

} ( Cat || {} ));

//  @prepros-prepend cat.eat.js
```

The `cat.eat.js` consists of:

```
var Cat = (function( cat ){

    cat.eat = function(){ return 'om nom nom'; };

    return cat;

} ( Cat || {} ));
```

I use [Prepros](http://alphapixels.com/prepros/) to minify and concatenate my project files.

**Somehow, Prepros doesn't concatenate the two `js` files. Am I missing something?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove the space between `@` and `slashes`.

```
var Cat = (function( cat ){

    cat.speak = function(){ return 'meew'; };

    return cat;

} ( Cat || {} ));

//@prepros-prepend cat.eat.js
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your help! :) Is this is a bug or desired behavior?

Comment: That's desired behavior but I am considering of changing that.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the info. By the way, Prepros is nice. Keep it up. :)